# excel 2003: file too big even its empty

Tags: microsoft-excel-2003

I have one excel file that consist of 3 sheets. Each sheet consist of text and image. The file grow up until 171KB. Then I copy one sheet become single file and save as a new file `(newbook.xls)`. And I get 136KB for this.

I have to try to reduce this file size with :

- crop the image, copy and paste to paint, resize it.
- copy from paint, paste to my new excel file
- cut the image, and paste special as JPEG
- then compress image

I did it to all image inside this file, but the become grow up until `145KB`.
I have confused, I try to delete all object and get `36KB (only text)`.
Then I try to delete all content in this sheet but this empty file have `29KB`, WHY ???

Answer (score 0):

Even if you crop the image, the resolution is still the same, What you can do is copy & paste the image on your desktop, right-click the image, select send to e-mail recipeint, then a pop-up window will appear asking you to choose the size, select any size that reduces your image then click attach. When you attach it will open a new e-mail. Copy the image again and paste in desktop, double click to open, then click copy, go to your excel worksheet and click paste.

Or

From the desktop

What you can do is copy & paste the image on your desktop, right-click the image, select send to compressed (zipped) folder, double the zipped folder copy the reduced image, open your excel workbook, click paste